# How to deal with missing data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've successfully created several plots with d3 by parsing XML files such as [this one](https://raw.github.com/hannorein/open_exoplanet_catalogue/master/systems/11%20Com.xml). 
Now I'm wondering how to deal with incomplete datasets. In my particular example, some sub-elements are missing in some elements. In that case I want d3 to discard the element and not display anything. At the moment, I am applying a filter to the dataset before feeding it into d3's data() function.

Is there a smarter of way of doing this on the fly? Ideally I'd just like to return `null` when setting an attribute and the required sub-element turns out not to exist.

Full disclaimer: I'm just starting to learn d3.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be obtained by setting the `display` property on the data joined DOM elements:

```js
elemSelection.style("display", function (d) { 
    return is_data_NA(d) ? "none" : null; 
});
```

Here is a short mock example: http://jsfiddle.net/rU4XL/

Note that by default, the function which accept `value` as a function such as [.attr](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-attr), [.style](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style), etc., will *remove the attribute or content* from the selection if the *value function* returns `null`. Hence, in this case, the `display` attribute would be removed from the elements in the `elemSelection` which have valid data.